# Animating div Y position smoothly with animejs

Tags: javascript, html, css, animejs

I want to make a div go up to `0px` from `100px` smoothly with animejs.

I have this div:

```
<div class="div"></div>
```

And style:

```
.div{ 
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  translateY: 100px;
}
```

And this is the js code:

```
anime({
   targets: [".div"],
   duration: 1000,
   easing: "easeOutElastic",
   translateY: "0px",
 })
```

I have tried doing the opposite like going down from `0px` to `100px` and its working well like that.But when I am trying like this the div is going to `0px` straight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `translateY` value as an [array](https://animejs.com/documentation/#fromToValues), first item being the start point and second being the end:

```js
translateY: [100, 0]
```

```js
anime({
  targets: [".div"],
  duration: 1000,
  easing: "easeOutElastic",
  translateY: [100, 0],
});
```

```css
.div {
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js"></script>

<div class="div">test</div>
```